# @SessionScoped for each user

Tags: jsf-2

I have many managed beans with :

```
@ManagedBean 
@SessionScoped
```

And when a user get login at my web application it works normally but the problem when a second user get login he use the managed beans of the previous user.

So i want that each user have their own managed beans even many users get login at the same time.

Comment: To exclude the obvious: the second user uses a completely different browser instance, right? The session is namely tied to a single browser instance and thus all opened windows/tabs of the same browser instance share the same session. To properly test multiple users, you'd better test using different browser instances, e.g. one user in Chrome and another user in Firefox.

Comment: How do your users login? A separately logged in user should have their own session regardless of browser instance. Also, what evidence do you have that the second user is using the Managed Beans of the previous user? It would be useful if you could post the Managed Bean code in question, along with a more descriptive explanation of what is happening for the first and second users.

Comment: thanks **BalusC** actually i have used the same browser.

Comment: **Jeremy Goodell** the problem it's solved because i used the same browser Chrome. In a tab i have the first user and in the other tab of Chrome i have the second user so they use the same session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can happen if you test the logins in the **same** browser instance. The session is namely tied to a single browser instance and thus all opened windows/tabs of the same browser instance share the same session. To properly test multiple users, you'd better test using different browser instances, e.g. one user in Chrome and another user in Firefox. Alternatively, you can also open a new "incognito" window in Chrome by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>. This will use a separate space for sessions/cookies/history which is *not* stored after you close the instance.